# Modes of convergence in infinite direct sums of $L^{2}$ spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

It is known that if a sequence of random variables converges in norm then there exists a subsequence which converges almost surely. That is: let $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq L^{2}\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\right)$
  be a sequence of square integrable random variables on the probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\right)$
 . If $X\in L^{2}\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\right)$
  is such that $\mathrm{E}_{P}\left(\left(X_{n}-X\right)^{2}\right)\longrightarrow0$
  as $n\longrightarrow\infty$
 , then there exists a subsequence $\left(X_{n_{k}}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\left(X_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
  such that $X_{n_{k}}\longrightarrow X$
  almost surely as $k\longrightarrow\infty$
 . My question is the following: does this holds for an infinite direct sum of $L^{2}$
  spaces? To be precise: consider a filtered probability space $\left(\Omega,\left(\mathcal{F}_{t}\right)_{t\in\mathbb{N}},\mathcal{F},P\right)$
 . Define: $$\oplus_{t=1}^{\infty}L^{2}\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_{t},P\right)\equiv\left\{ \left(X\left(t\right)\right)_{t=1}^{\infty}:\, X\left(t\right)\in L^{2}\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_{t},P\right)\forall t,\,\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\mathrm{E}_{P}\left(X\left(t\right)^{2}\right)<\infty\right\}.$$
 Let $\left(\left(X_{n}\left(t\right)\right)_{t=1}^{\infty}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\oplus_{t=1}^{\infty}L^{2}\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_{t},P\right)$
  be such that $\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\mathrm{E}_{P}\left(\left(X_{n}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right)^{2}\right)\longrightarrow0$
  as $n\longrightarrow\infty$
  for some $\left(X\left(t\right)\right)_{t=1}^{\infty}\in\oplus_{t=1}^{\infty}L^{2}\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_{t},P\right).$ Does there exists a subsequence $\left(\left(X_{n_{k}}\left(t\right)\right)_{t=1}^{\infty}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\left(\left(X_{n}\left(t\right)\right)_{t=1}^{\infty}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
  such that, for every $t\geq1$
 , $X_{n_{k}}\left(t\right)\longrightarrow X\left(t\right)$
  almost surely? I worked out a proof that seems to be sound, but I'm not sure of a couple of passage I did. The proof is as follows. I indicate inside parenthesis the passage I am not sure about. First I claim that $$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}E\left(\left(X_{n}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right)^{2}\right)\rightarrow0\Rightarrow P\left[\sup_{t}\left|X_{n}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right|>\epsilon\right]\rightarrow0
 $$ for every $\epsilon>0
 $.

Proof of the claim. I prove the counterpositive. Suppose that there exist $\epsilon,\delta>0$ such that, for every $\bar{n}$, there exists an $n\left(\bar{n}\right)\geq\bar{n}$ such that $$P\left[\sup_{t}\left|X_{n\left(\bar{n}\right)}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right|>\epsilon\right]\geq\delta.$$
Then it must be true that (this the passage I am not sure about) $$P\left[\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\left(X_{n\left(\bar{n}\right)}\left(t\right)-X_{n\left(\bar{n}\right)}\left(t\right)\right)^{2}\geq\epsilon^{2}\right]\geq\delta.$$
Call $E=\left[\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\left(X_{n\left(\bar{n}\right)}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right)^{2}\geq\epsilon^{2}\right]\in\mathcal{F}$. We have:

$$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}E\left(\left(X_{n\left(\bar{n}\right)}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right)^{2}\right) = E\left(\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\left(X_{n\left(\bar{n}\right)}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right)^{2}\right)
\geq\int_{E}\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\left(X_{n\left(\bar{n}\right)}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right)^{2}\mathrm{d}P \geq \epsilon^{2}\delta.$$

Then, for every $\bar{n}$, there exists an $n\left(\bar{n}\right)\geq\bar{n}$ such that $$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}E\left(\left(X_{n\left(\bar{n}\right)}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right)^{2}\right)\geq\epsilon^{2}\delta$$ and this completes the proof of the claim. $\square$

Now I show that if $P\left[\sup_{t}\left|X_{n}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right|>\epsilon\right]\rightarrow0$
  then there exists a subsequence $\left(\left(X_{n_{k}}\left(t\right)\right)_{t\in\mathbb{N}}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\left(\left(X_{n}\left(t\right)\right)_{t\in\mathbb{N}}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
  such that $$\sup_{t}\left|X_{n_{k}}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right|\longrightarrow0\qquad\mbox{a.s.}$$
 First observe that, for every $k>0$
, there exists an integer $n_{k}$
 such that$$P\left[\sup_{t}\left|X_{n_{k}}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right|>\frac{1}{k}\right]\leq\frac{1}{2^{k}}.$$
 This implies that$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P\left[\sup_{t}\left|X_{n_{k}}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right|>\frac{1}{k}\right]<\infty.$$
 Finally, observe that, for every $\epsilon>0$
, $$\left[\sup_{t}\left|X_{n_{k}}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right|>\epsilon\,\mbox{i.o.}\right]\subseteq\left[\sup_{t}\left|X_{n_{k}}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right|>\frac{1}{k}\,\mbox{i.o.}\right],$$
 so that$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P\left[\sup_{t}\left|X_{n_{k}}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right|>\frac{1}{k}\right]<\infty  
\Rightarrow P\left[\sup_{t}\left|X_{n_{k}}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right|>\frac{1}{k}\,\mbox{i.o.}\right]=0  
\Rightarrow P\left[\sup_{t}\left|X_{n_{k}}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right|>\epsilon\,\mbox{i.o.}\right]=0  \forall\epsilon>0
\Rightarrow\sup_{t}\left|X_{n_{k}}\left(t\right)-X\left(t\right)\right|\rightarrow0  \mbox{a.s.}$$
 and this completes the proof  $\square\square$

Comment: A diagonalization argument should do what you want.  Do you know the "diagonal subsequence" proof that $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ is compact?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not know the argument that you mention. Can you be more precise? (a link to some website with the proof that you mention would be enough). Thanks a lot.